# Launcher and Chooser in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am not able to find a way (even with Mango SDK) in which I can show a chooser (say PhoneNumberChooserTask), and get all details about a contact...

Only Name and PhoneNumber is available. For other information like address, I have to use a different chooser. Is there any way in which I can show a chooser (anyone) and get all details...

1. Phone number
2. Email address
3. Photo of the contact

etc.

let me clarify the issue here...

The following code will not work. I want to show a chooser in such a way that it grabs all details. Showing multiple choosers, as I said is not what I want. Imagine asking someone to choose the same contact 3 times to get Email, PhoneNumber and Address.

> ```
>       EmailAddressChooserTask ect = new EmailAddressChooserTask();
>         ect.Completed += new EventHandler<EmailResult>(ect_Completed);
>         ect.Show();
> ```

```
        PhoneNumberChooserTask pct = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
        pct.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(pct_Completed);
        pct.Show();

        AddressChooserTask act = new AddressChooserTask();
        act.Completed += new EventHandler<AddressResult>(act_Completed);
        act.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v7.1 (Mango) you can use the [Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) class. You can use the [SearchAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts.searchasync%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) method providing whatever search criteria you want ([DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.filterkind%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is the most likely) and then handle the [SearchCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts.searchcompleted%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) event and use the [ContactsSearchEventArgs.Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contactssearcheventargs.results%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to access the returned [Contact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) objects.

From there, you can use the [GetPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact.getpicture%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) method to retrieve the contact image, and the various [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) of the Contact object to access all the other information.

Hopefully that will get you started. You can find more information in the [Microsoft.Phone.UserData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh220665%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the following tasks:

- [AddressChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.addresschoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [EmailAddressChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailaddresschoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [PhoneNumberChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I should have been clearer. I have updated my question above.